# How to increase the icon() size in a shiny app using css or parameter

Tags: r, shiny, icons

How can I increase the size of the `icon()` in a `shiny` app

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css")
  ),
  
  # Rest of your UI code
  icon("square_check", class = "fa")  # Apply the "fa" class to the icon
  # ...
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Server code
  # ...
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```r
icon("square_check", class = "fa", style = "font-size: 30px;")
```

Answer (score 1):

The css property is `font-size`

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  icon("home"),
  icon("home", style = "font-size: 24px;"),
  icon("home", style = "font-size: 40px;")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Server code
  # ...
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]